# Can I share a Hex with my familiar via the Share Spell class feature?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, magic, familiars, witch

After looking through my abilities and spells, I believe that I found a way to enhance my cat to finally do damage by itself without changing its stats or actively casting spells. However, this would be the Hex "Prehensile Hair". Since it does not specify in the description of "Share Spell" what does and doesn't count as a spell, can I share Hexes and other off-brand magics with my cat?

Because having a cat that beard-punches would be awsome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hexes are extraordinary (Ex), spell-like (Sp), or supernatural (Su), not spells. Notably, they don’t use spell slots and they don’t provoke attacks of opportunity, things spells generally do (actually, for that matter, spell-like abilities usually provoke too, so I’m not sure how that works). The familiar’s ability to Share Spells specifically refers to spells, not to any other kind of ability.

So strictly speaking, familiars can only share in your spells, not your hexes or other non-spell abilities. Even the ones that are “spell-*like*” (since spell-like abilities differ from spells in several important ways, and in a lot of ways really aren’t all that much “like” spells to begin with).

That said, talk to your DM. The familiar and Share Spells were written for the sorcerer and wizard; the wording actually is straight from D&D 3.5. Hexes weren’t anticipated when the ability was written. While there probably *are* abusive shenanigans that get made available by opening Share Spells up (particularly if you open it up to all abilities, rather than just hexes), hopefully your DM trusts you enough not to do that if you do find any (and hopefully you deserve that trust).

Comment: As a possible analogy, the [Improved Share Spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-share-spells) feat specifically disallows spell-like abilities.